# What is the time complexity of breaking string into valid words?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The problem is like this:

> Given an English dictionary (implemented as a hashmap (word -> meaning)) and a string without spaces, output all possible combinations of valid English words that when combined, reproduce the input string.

The problem can be solved with recursion/dynamic programming, but when analyzing the time complexity, I am confused:

1. Imagine the dictionary to include every possible character permutations(every sequence of chars is a valid word), then given the string, for each position between 2 chars, you can choose to insert a space or not, there are n-1 such positions, so there are 2^(n-1) possible results. The complexity of any algorithm generating these results has to be at least O(2^n).
2. I can use a dynamic programming algorithm to do this. Suppose result[i] is the possible splits for substring i..N, to calculate result[j]:

   `for k in range j+1 to N:
       if s[j:k] is a valid word:
          merge the word in the result[k]`

   Since we are calculating result[N] back to result[0], and each of these calculations take O(N) (because subproblems we depend on have been calculated), the time complexity should be O(N^2).

Why can I get different conclusions from the 2 kinds of reasoning, and which is correct?

Comment: I guess size of dictionary must be included in time complexity somehow, because it is part of the input.

Comment: The complexity depends on the content of the dictionary; suppose for example the dictionary contains only 5 letter words than there is at most one way to split the string. And it is straight forward to find the split. The worst case is given by your reasoning 1.

Comment: Your analysis for (1) is correct; for (2) it's wrong.  The problem in the latter case is that there could be many (not just 1) ways to split the remaining part `s[k+1:N]` into words, so `merge the word into result[k]` has to take (at least) time proportional to the number of ways to do so.

Comment: (OTOH, if you wanted to find just *some* particular way of splitting the string into words (that, optionally, maximises some score), then the DP in your (2) can accomplish this in just O(n^2) time, assuming that you use a data structure that allows the operations "Add given character to start" and "Test if current string is in the dictionary" in O(1).)

Comment: What should I do if I only want the solution that is formed by the smallest number of word? Do i have to compute all the solutions and choose the smallest one or is it another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the size of the input string `n`, you should introduce an additional parameter `r` representing the size of the result and use this in your analysis.  "The size of the result" in this case would be something like the sum of the number of words in each valid combination.

In your description of the algorithm you gloss over how you merge the intermediate results in the loop body.  You are implicitly assuming this can be done in constant time.  However as you noted this leads to a contradictory result.

The analysis is simpler if you separate the algorithm into two phases:

- In phase I, you build a data structure indicating positions where words can be embedded in the string.  This can be done in `Θ(n^2)` time, assuming you can check whether each substring is a word in amortized constant time.
- In phase II, you traverse this data structure to output the list of word combinations.  This can be done in linear time in the size of the output, `Θ(r)`.

So in total this algorithm would have a time complexity of `Θ(n^2 + r)`.

*Note:* To be formally correct you should also consider the time required to read in the list of English words.  If you want to account for this you can introduce an additional variable `d` and add a `+ d` term to the time complexity.

*Also:* The `n^2` part of this bound may be improved by using the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) to find all matching substrings instead of looking up each substring in a hash table.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to use Aho_Corasick algorithm to find substrings? I think that algorithm is designed for a different problem, like finding word `abc` and `bcd` from `abcd`. But this word-breaking problem doesn't allow the words to overlap. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NeoWang: The output of the Aho-Corasick algorithm will tell you which words are found at what positions. You can order that list by position. Then, grab a word that starts at position 0. Say it's "foo." Now, look to see if the list contains a word that starts at position 3 (i.e. start position plus word length), and so on. And, by the way, the Aho-Corasick algorithm is much more useful than just "finding 'abc' and 'bcd' in 'abcd'. It can find occurrences of many words or phrases in a single pass of a document. Virus scanners use something very similar to quickly check executables.